# What is the state of the art of splitting a binary file by size?

Tags: history, split

#### Some background you can happily skip

Twenty years ago or so, when navigating the web costed a lot, when I was a Windows-only user, and when CDs/DVDs were a large storage means, and when sharing video files with a friend or relative would sometimes require to split the file over multiple CDs/DVDs, copying them on the other computer's person and then rejoining the pieces, I used to use [HJSplit](https://hjsplit.it.softonic.com/). Worked like a charm.

#### The motivation

Fast-forward 20 years, I recently found myself in need for such a utility on Linux, due to the slow/unreliable connection not allowing me to easily `scp` stuff across physically very distant Linux systems. The solution that came to mind was to split the file and transfer the pieces, then rejoin them.

That's how I found HJSplit was Windows-only and that [`lxsplit`](https://lxsplit.sourceforge.net/) existed and worked like a charm as well, so all is good.

#### My question

But [`lxsplit`](https://lxsplit.sourceforge.net/) is abandoned since 2008, so maybe some other (better?) solution has come up in these 15 years.

What is the state of the art in this field, i.e. splitting and rejoining big binary files, on Linux?¹

#### Additional motivation

I also thought that conceptually speaking, splitting a file and rejoining it is a very simple task, so I wondered whether I could write my own program for doing so. I tried, and got something working in a few hours, but it's at least ~5 times slower than `lxsplit`. Before diving into profiling and benchmarking, I wanted to know whether there's other similar programs that have even better performance than `lxsplit`.

---

(¹) I'm not interested in alternative workflows for accomplishing the original task of transfering a big file between two systems. Yes, today you'd probably upload it to Dropbox/Onedrive/GoogleDrive/whatever from one system and download it from the other.

Comment: Have you check `split` command?

Comment: Have you considered `rsync`, a restartable copy command?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I did not know of it, thanks.

Comment: @roaima, please, read the note at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I read your note and I decided it would still be remiss of me not to mention `rsync`. It's simpler and more efficient to use than either of your proposed transfer mechanisms

Comment: @RomeoNinov, `split` seems to be often slighly faster than `lxsplit` indeed.

Comment: @roaima, in this case what to say? Thanks for the info.

Comment: you can also try your luck with wireguard, it can help with unreliable connection to some extent. for example it allows peers to reconnect with a new public IP. it just has to happen fast enough for things to not time out...

Comment: For something so simple, it shouldn't matter whether the software was last updated this year, 10 years ago, or 30 years ago.

Comment: Easy method to split is WinRAR / WinZip and archive files with fixed size (multipart).

Comment: 7zip will split files, too.

Comment: The only thing that would make one solution "state of the art" here would be using reflink support to avoid needing to copy bytes around. Otherwise anything you do today will be 100% identical to how it would work 40 years ago. Using reflinks, though, only works when your chunks are block-aligned and your system is using a modern enough filesystem to support them; so most of the time you don't _want_ the "state of the art" and should be sticking with tried-and-true.

Comment: (If you _are_ using block-aligned chunks, though, using reflinks will make the process basically instant, _and_ mean that the files with the chunks don't take up extra space on the disk, since they're reusing the same disk space that's already used for the original).

Comment: "But lxsplit is abandoned since 2008." -- Why is that an issue? It still compiles without a problem...

Comment: @DanMašek, you're right, but if a tool was abandoned 15 years ago, I'm prone to think something better has popped up in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Enlico, ...there are spaces in which that's true, but splitting a file into bytes is not one of them; it's such a simple operation that once you're doing it correctly, there's nothing to improve (except for weird corner-case optimizations like the reflink approach mentioned above). It's not like there are places doing it wrong could break security, or need to support formats/protocols that change over time.

Comment: Back even before your time we used to do this a lot over floppies, and I remember using something that would allow for unreadable or missing disks. I just can't remember what tool that was. Obviously it required extra storage in proportion to how much redundancy you required.

Comment: @pipe, some variant of [`par2`](https://github.com/Parchive/par2cmdline) perhaps?

Comment: You say state of the art. Anything from the 1980's should be fine. I can't think of anything new about cutting a file that could possibly be invented. I remember being frustrated in the early 1990's that there was nothing on the MS-DOS/Windows machine that I was forced to use, that could do this.

Answer (score 25):

The [`split`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=split&apropos=0&sektion=1) command has been part of Unix since the ancient days, and while it was originally a text processing command that split in lines, modern implementations also work with binary files. `split -b` is in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) and [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#split).

To split, choose a size for the pieces (the last piece will be whatever's left) and a prefix to the file names of the pieces. (You don't get to choose the numbering style or an extension for the file name.)

```
split -b 1440k myfile.bin part-
```

To concatenate the pieces, just use `cat`. Use a shell wildcard for the pieces and they'll be in the correct order.

```
cat part-?? >myfile.bin
```

Note that you're guaranteed to get the parts in the correct order, but there's no check for missing parts. Also there's no protection against mixing parts from different files. Use a command such as `cksum`, `md5sum`, `md5`, or whatever is available on both systems to calculate a checksum of the original file and the reassembled file.

Comment: (As regards the concactenation,) I might have to double check and test for different file sizes, but earlier I gave a few tries to `lxsplit -j part1` vs `cat part*` and the former turned out to be faster.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev With `split`, the order from shell wildcard expansion is guaranteed to be correct, because it uses a fixed-length sequence of letters, not a variable-length sequence of digits.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution that came to mind was to split the file and transfer the pieces, then rejoin them.

Then this sounds like the XY problem. Just use rsync:

```
rsync -avzh verybigfileordirectory user@slowremotehost.example.com:/home/user/destination/
```

You can stop this and start it as required. It will work out what data is missing at the remote end (small negotiation overhead) and copy only that. It does require rsync at both ends.

Comment: There's no XY problem. Refer to the last paragraph in my question + the footnote. But thanks for pointing out what was already pointed out in the comments to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest zip, which is specifically oriented towards binary files.

Although some users might be wary of it due to a certain redolence of DOS :-)

Comment: As I said, my interest is specifically in splitting a file in chunks.

Comment: Yes, which zip does very nicely.

Comment: Then, please, add code to support the answer. Zip is notoriously known to compress files. If it does more, then clarify.

Comment: Please see the zip man page, specifically the section on Split archives. "zip version 3.0 and later can create split archives.  A split archive is a standard zip archive split over multiple files."

Comment: @Enlico all common Windows compression formats like zip, rar, 7z... support splitting

Comment: _"Use `-s` to set the split size and create a split archive."_ from [zip (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).

Comment: Sorry everybody, I should have put more detail in to start with. However I'd not touched it for decades until a few days ago when I had to break a very large amount of "legal crap" up to email to somebody with unknown tools, and to my surprise I found that Zip (on Linux) was ideal for the job. Hence since it was written from day one to support binary files, I feel it's probably a better choice than using something like split which wasn't. And I say that despite my strong preference for the "software tools" approach which is the "unix way". Of course, rsync etc. would be better if available...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, what do you mean that split wasn't "written to support" binary files? It has a byte-by-byte mode; what else is needed to support binary files? It's not like UNIX is Windows with horrors like automated newline conversion that make binary and text different from each other; particularly back in the 70s when `split` was designed and Unicode wasn't a thing yet, a byte is a byte is a byte. (Yes, you had character sets/encodings, but everyone worked in 8 bits so it didn't matter to a tool like `split`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy precisely what Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' put in his answer. It was originally for processing text, and still comes from GNU textutils rather than from binary utilities.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, right, but _traditional UNIX systems don't have a meaningful text/binary distinction_. `split` _supports_ splitting by line, which is of course textual in nature, but because the OS's file I/O doesn't care, that doesn't change anything at all about how its byte-count-based methods work.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, ...for something comparable, think about `wc` -- in `wc -l` mode it operates line-by-line (and needs to think about actual content), but for `wc -c` mode (counting bytes) it _doesn't read a file at all_ unless it has to, and just asks the OS to `seek()` to the end and `tell()` it how far from the beginning it is. That kind of easy optimization exists all over the GNU toolkit; they're not going to do something inefficient when there's an obvious better choice, even if they support the inefficient thing for benefit of a separate use case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am fully aware of that thank you, and you forget to point out that things are simplified by the fact that unix only uses a single character for newline rather than two >:-) If you really want /fun/ I suggest sitting in on some of the discussions of the mainframe reenactors and their interminable arguments about how to reconcile that kind of system's record-based I/O (with the record size being an attribute of the file etc.) with modern programming languages' expectations.

Comment: If you're well aware of the relevant factors, why are you suggesting that `split -b` is likely to do something wrong?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't disagree with anything you're saying, but as I'm sure you're aware, `wc -l` is one of those "unix horrors" which does what the manpage says instead of what you might naively assume it does.  Namely, it counts newlines instead of lines, so that `printf "line1\nline2" | wc -l` prints `1` instead of `2` (because the input is not a "text file").  Sort of the unix counterpart to the "Windows horrors" of 2-byte newline sequences and not being able to concatenate text files (properly) with `cat`.

Comment: I agree (in a non-contrarian, serious, correctness-focused way) with `wc -l`'s output; `line1\nline2` _isn't_ a 2-line text file: `while read line; do ...; done <file` will only iterate once. Any software that pretends that stray content without a terminal newline is a valid line of text is _wrong_, and papering over a bugs by misreporting contents is just making for better-hidden/more-obscure bugs -- Postel's Law seemed like good sense back in the 90s, but this isn't the 90s anymore: we've learned that silently accepting invalid content _causes more obscure bugs_ than reporting it.

Comment: As such, misbehaving when something doesn't meet the spec for a valid line of text _is_ better than pretending it was valid; it gives you at least a decent chance of being able to detect, f/e, when you had a file mistakenly truncated without a complete, successful final write.

Comment: Kids, /please/: this doesn't help answer OP's question. Please refer to https://www.collectedcurios.com/sequentialart.php?s=13

Comment: @jrw32982, if you wanted `printf "line1\nline2" | wc -l` to print 2, then you'd want `printf "line1" | wc -l` to print 1; then also `printf "l" | wc -l` should print 1, and why should `printf "" | wc -l` shoud print something other than 1, given you've not added/removed line breaks but just removed a character? And you've ended up with an empty file being 1 line long. Come on.